# Different Disk Transfer Speed

Tags: windows-10

When transferring big files 2-20GB in size from HDD to an external HDD, explorer reports 100MB/s but task manager shows ~220MB/s. I understand the overhead but not that much!

Can someone tell me why and whether a way exists to harness that by maybe using some other file manager or file copier software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a file is being *copied* at 100MB/s then by definition it must be being read at 100MB/s and written at 100MB/s.  Task manager is showing a total aggregate data rate while Explorer is showing the rate at which data is transferred from one drive to another.

Comment: Oh so its showing aggregate of the total I/O! Thanks.

Comment: @UmairAhmed Yes. I did a quick test on my system from one drive to another and under the "Performance" tab in Task Manager I see ~160MB/s reading from one drive, ~160MB/s writing to another and about ~320MB/s "disk" usage for the Explorer process.  This is about what I would expect.  The Explorer "copy" dialog showed the ~160MB/s rate.